# Algebraic Curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $F$ be a non-constant polynomial in $k[X_1,...,X_n]$, $k$ algebraically closed.

> Show that $\mathbb A^n \setminus \mathrm{V}(F)$ is infinite if $n\geq 1$, and $\mathrm{V}(F)$ in infinite if $n\geq 2$.
>
> Conclude that the complement of any proper algebraic set is infinite.

Comment: Sounds to be homework!

Comment: I assume $A^n/V(F)$ is supposed to be something else, and my goodness tagged with algebraic-topology?!

Answer (score 2):

First, because $k$ is algebraically closed, it is infinite.

Second, if you have a polynomial $\rm P$ in $k[\rm X_1, ... , X_n]$, then it is always possible to find a line in $\mathbb A^n$ such that $\mathrm P$ restricted to that line is a non zero one variable polynomial. Then such a polynomial can have only a finite number of zeros. Hence $\mathbb A^n \backslash\rm V(P)$ is infinite.

Comment: I wish LaTeX didn't italicise capital letters by default...

Comment: With some options, you can ask that to LaTeX !